# Variable shared between two instances of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Without using inheritance, can we have a variable shared between two instances of a class? 
The problem is that the variable needs 3.5GB. Using inheritance is not a good option as I might or might not load this variable.

Comment: You can have multiple references to the same object in memory. That's nothing to do with inheritance per se.

Comment: I don't understand you well, which memory do you mean? Do you mean to pass the variable from the first instance to the second one?

Comment: I can only give a vague suggestion to a vague question. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @khelwood I have a class named `Go_DB` that needs to load a variable/object (call it `big_obj`) of size 3.5GB. Now, I need to construct two instances:
`x = Go_DB('')` ; `y = Go_DB('')` . In this case, each of `x` and `y` will have its own `big_obj`. What I am thinking is to have one instance of `big_obj` shared between `x` and `y` . I know this is very bad OOP.

Comment: Why can't you do that, why cant you have big_obj = "blah" then x=Go_DB(big_obj)  y=Go_DB(big_obj)?  I'm not sure i'm understanding properly what the issue is here.

Comment: Yes I can do that, and I know that. You are right. But I was thinking there might be some keyword, maybe `static`, that enables me to share some vars between two or more instances.

Comment: On a second thought, that will not be useful (passing the object as an argument to the class), as I am storing the object in the `self` of the class, and as I understand, each class will have its own self copy.

Comment: I think the pattern you are looking for is a Singleton. The two instances could reference the go_db singleton.

Comment: Define that member as a class variable (not as an instance variable) then it will be shareable among  multiple instances of same class. If you wish I can write a simple example.

Comment: @hygull Please do.

Comment: Okay, thanks, wait.

Comment: I hope that my answer clarified your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @hygull it did. Thank you.

Comment: @innuendo Even if you pass your object to the `__init__` method and assign it to an attribute via `self.`, it's still _shared_. The data won't be _copied_ unless you do something to copy it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class variables for this. Please have a look at the below simple example where a family shares a single account.

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

```
class FamilyAccount(object):
    total_amount = 0 # class variable

    def __init__(self, fullname, age):
        self.fullname = fullname # instance variable
        self.age = age           # instance variable

    def credit(self, amount):
        FamilyAccount.total_amount += amount

    def debit(self, amount):
        FamilyAccount.total_amount -= amount

    def details(self):
        print("Fullname: ", self.fullname)
        print("Age     : ", self.age)
        print("Amount  : ", self.total_amount)
        print() # new line

# Create account for Rishikesh Agrawani
account1 = FamilyAccount("Rishikesh Agrawani", 26)
# Rishikesh Agrawani credits 1000
account1.credit(1000)
# Print account information of Rishikesh Agrawani
account1.details() # 1000


# Create account for Shay Banon
account2 = FamilyAccount("Shay Banon", 30)
# Shay Banon debits 500
account2.debit(500)
# Print account information of Shay Banon
account2.details() # 500

# Print account information of Rishikesh Agrawani (again)
account1.details() # 500

# Fullname:  Rishikesh Agrawani
# Age     :  26
# Amount  :  1000

# Fullname:  Shay Banon
# Age     :  30
# Amount  :  500

# Fullname:  Rishikesh Agrawani
# Age     :  26
# Amount  :  500
```

> If you want to initialize the class variable with some other value like `10` other than `0`, you can modify the above code as below.

```
class FamilyAccount(object):
    total_amount = 0 # class variable

    def __init__(self, fullname, age, amount = 0, set_amount = False):
        if set_amount: 
            # If you want to reset amount for all members
            # total_amount will be re-intialized (visible to all instances)
            FamilyAccount.total_amount = amount

        self.fullname = fullname # instance variable
        self.age = age           # instance variable

    def credit(self, amount):
        FamilyAccount.total_amount += amount

    def debit(self, amount):
        FamilyAccount.total_amount -= amount

    def details(self):
        print("Fullname: ", self.fullname)
        print("Age     : ", self.age)
        print("Amount  : ", self.total_amount)
        print() # new line

# Create account for Rishikesh Agrawani
account1 = FamilyAccount("Rishikesh Agrawani", 26, 10, set_amount = True)
# Rishikesh Agrawani credits 1000
account1.credit(1000)
# Print account information of Rishikesh Agrawani
account1.details() # 1010


# Create account for Shay Banon
account2 = FamilyAccount("Shay Banon", 30)
# Shay Banon debits 500
account2.debit(500)
# Print account information of Shay Banon
account2.details() # 510

# Print account information of Rishikesh Agrawani (again)
account1.details() # 510

# Fullname:  Rishikesh Agrawani
# Age     :  26
# Amount  :  1010

# Fullname:  Shay Banon
# Age     :  30
# Amount  :  510

# Fullname:  Rishikesh Agrawani
# Age     :  26
# Amount  :  510
```

Comment: @hyugull Just one little issue I am having here, suppose I need to pass a value to initialize `total_amount` to some value at `account1`, can this be done?  As this is out of the scope of `__init__` .

Comment: Yes, that can be done with little modification in existing code. I am adding code snippet `the same example`. Please check. Here I have used the concept of default arguments. Thank you.

Comment: `set_amount` decides whether you want to reset amount or not. If you will not check it, you will get unwanted result as it will be reset by all instantiations `(object creations)` and we know class variable is shared by al instances of same class.

Comment: We do not need to pass the value of default argument's (Keyword arguments) like `amount = 0`, `set_amount = False`, in this case the default values will be taken, you can override if you wish by passing values as I passed while creating 1st account `account1`.

Comment: You saved my day. Yes, I can read the code. I will just have to flag-in the first instance creation and load the 3.5GB data.